# NSManagedObjectContext reference has not the same state

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm relatively new to this topic some maybe it's a newbie question...

I have Class A and Class B both working with the same context(passed it through from the delegate). Now I add something in Class A on a ManagedObject. If I check the real DB I see that the insert was successful.

Now, Class B gets informed because of a delegate method. I'm getting the data with a executeFetchRequest, but the newly added object is not in this list...

Why are these two contexts out of sync?

### Update:

I have a object ListName which has a list of ListItems. If I do a fetch on ListName and getting the list from there it is out of sync. If I do the fetch on ListItem I get all items..this is strange!

Comment: Are the two entities related in the data modele.g. something like `EntityA.bs<-->EntityB.as`?

Comment: Yes ther is a One to many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [reset](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/reset) has helped

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing these classes on two different threads? If not, there is really no reason to have two managedObjectContexts.

Comment: now should be in the same thread but I dont have two manageObjectContexts, I just have a reference on it. I'm getting it if the class is instaced....

Comment: If you are only using one MOC then there is nothing to be out of sync with. Are you calling save? I would double check your fetchRequest and make sure any predicates and such are correct.

Comment: ah just found this: I have a object ListName which has a list of ListItems. If I do a fetch on ListName and getting the list from there it is out of sync. If I do the fetch on ListItem I get all items..this is strange!